# Windows 10 - Set default browser for individual application

Tags: windows-10, browser, microsoft-teams

I use Firefox as my default browser on my PC, but when I'm working from home I use Firefox Dev Edition for work related accounts (with a different sync profile and password manager).

We use Microsoft Teams to communicate. When people send me links to work related pages (i.e. self hosted GitLab) I would like them to open in Firefox Dev Edition (which isn't the default), rather than having to copy and paste them.

Is there a way to do this either in Teams or in Windows 10?